# I minimize one Form and minimize several

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a form and through this I press a button and a new form opens. **If I click minimize this new form, the form I call this form from is minimized as well**. How could I make sure the form from which I call the new form is not minimized?
Maybe I have to enable some property in the form or something.

Of course, I tried with the following code and with the form propety singleFixed but the two forms are minimized:

```
private void bminimize_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
}
```

Maybe have I to create this new form as subform or something like this?

**EDIT:** How I call this new form:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
   DateTime rnow = DateTime.Now;
   Chronometer chrono = new chronometer();
                
   var resultchrono = chrono.ShowDialog();
   if (resultchrono == DialogResult.OK)
   {
      ...
   }
```

Comment: How do you open the new form? That sounds like it could be being opened as a child window or something.

Comment: @AKX hi, let me put the code in the question. I am going to edit it!

Comment: Modal form blocks access to a parent form. Minimizing both makes the most sense, otherwise how user would know he is not allowed to interract and where should restore option resides?

Comment: @GetData Its because of: ``chrono.ShowDialog();``. Show the dialog with ``chrono.Show();``. But you will have to handle returned values differently

Comment: @Tofik that works :) I have never used ShowDialog(owner), Have I to put as a parameter the name of the owner of this form? Is my first time using this method, so how could I call the owner here?

Comment: @GetData Depends on what is your follow up code and if you need the ``DialogResult`` in the same function. If you do, then use AKX answer.

Answer (score 2):

You're using [`ShowDialog()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.showdialog?view=netcore-3.1#System_Windows_Forms_Form_ShowDialog), which is documented thus, emphasis mine:

> This version of the ShowDialog method does not specify a form or control as its owner. **When this version is called, the currently active window is made the owner of the dialog box. If you want to specify a specific owner, use the other version of this method.**

If you need the dialog result, you'll need to use the [`ShowDialog(owner)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.showdialog?view=netcore-3.1#System_Windows_Forms_Form_ShowDialog_System_Windows_Forms_IWin32Window_) form of the call with say, the desktop window handle.

Comment: Nice, I tried using just .Show() and works. I have never used ShowDialog(owner), Have I to put as a parameter the name of the owner of this form? Is my first time using this method, so how could I call the owner here?

Comment: I am trying with this: var resultchrono = chrono.ShowDialog(this.owner); but doesn't work.

Comment: You must pass the form itself, i.e, `ShowDialog(this)` or  `ShowDialog(myFormVariable)`. This ensures that the dialog form always appears above the specified owner. Works with `Show` as well.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes thank you for your answer. I am trying it but I have not reference about the main form, is called mForm but is not working with this.owner and I have not any variable of this form.

Comment: You can get it with `Application.OpenForms[0]`.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes is not working :( I search first the form by name and store in a variable the number of this form, in this case is one, then I call the method as you can see here: chrono.ShowDialog(Application.OpenForms[formGalv3]) but not working

Comment: I you don't want to minimize other windows, don't use `ShowDialog` but use `Show` and do not specify an owner.

Answer (score 0):

Its because of: `chrono.ShowDialog();`. Show the dialog with `chrono.Show();` . But you will have to handle returned values differently.

If you need the `DialogResult` in the same method in which you open the window, then use AKX´s answer.